# Azure AD returns non JWT Tokens when exchanging the OAuth2 code for an access token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, microsoft-identity-platform, personal-access-token

I have an Azure AD App on my tenant that is configured to accept multiple tenants AND personal accounts.

I follow the procedure to retrieve an AccessToken as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

When I receive the "code" in my app from the Microsoft web page, I exchange it for an access token calling the endpoint "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token".

Here the behavior differs whether the user that logs in is a work account or a personal account.

With work accounts, I receive a normal JWT Token and everybody is happy: I can decode the token and read the claims.

With personal accounts, I receive another token, that is not a JWT Token and I don't have any clue on how to:

1. validate this token
2. read a few information from the user (specifically, the email of the user)

Could you please help me understand how to perform these two actions?

NOTE: I have seen the answers here: [Microsoft as OAuth2 provider for personal accounts does not issue JWT access tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68879862/microsoft-as-oauth2-provider-for-personal-accounts-does-not-issue-jwt-access-tok) but my case is slightly different, since I don't want to access MS Graph with this token, I just need to retrieve the email of the user.

Thanks!

cghersi

Answer (score 1):

The `access_token` in OAuth2 is not required to be an JWT per the OAuth specification.
However Microsoft supports [OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc), that provides an `id_token`. The `id_token` is always an JWT.

To "upgrade" your OAuth request to an OpenID Connect request you simply have to add the scope `openid` (and possibly `email` to ensure you get an email).
Then when you exchange your `code` to an `access_token` you also get an `id_token`

Comment: Thanks @Nisd, I can get the id_token, but it has no relevant claims for me to find the email of the user (even if I put the email scope). So, is there a MS REST API that I can call with the id_token to retrieve the basic details of the user, like the email?

Comment: @CristianoGhersi

Sounds strange. Looking at our own codebase we are able to extract email and name from the id_token.

In the Azure Portal, have you tried adding email and openid as requested claims by your application?

Alternatively you should be able to call the UserInfo endpoint at https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo with your access_token.

Comment: How does the example for delegated access in postman get the JWT then, it looks like it follows the exact same flow for generating a code, and token

Comment: Off-topic: seeing the words "OpenID" and "upgrade" in a single sentence makes me chuckle... isn't OpenID the "old" piece of tech (heck, the spec was drafted in 2005!), that was superseded by OAuth2?

Comment: @Lukasz032 Yes, OpenID is old and was replaced by OAuth2. However OpenID Connect is new and build on-top of OAuth2.